# Filtering AD users by Company Name

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am looking to get a list of users and their email addresses which has a particular company name in AD using power-shell. The users are all apart of a Dynamic Distribution List.

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: What have you written so far? Which parts are working? Which parts are not working? Please edit any relevant code/output into your question.

Comment: Also, are you sysadmin, email server admin, or an end-user?  (End user can only really use core and AD module cmdlets, and then only with security opened up to allow it.)  And what version of PowerShell do you have available to you.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you mean the company name attribute in AD has been set for these users? Or are you saying the email address contains the company name?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a dynamic group to work against.  The following may work.  Basically pull all the group members user objects and if they match the search string (email address portion, which we have to add to the data pull, because it's not a default property), then put their user object in an array.  Export the array.  Done.  This code works with user level permissions (once PS is unlocked).

If Get-ADGroupMember does not work against a Dynamic Distribution List, I'm sure the Exchange PS module has something that does.  Tweak the first line of the code to use that.  Of course you have to be an Exchange admin (the right kind) to use the modules.

```
$listGroupMembers = Get-ADGroupMember "CN=groupname,OU=Distribution Groups,DC=eviltwin,DC=com"
$listOutput = @()
$searchstring = "evilcorp.com"

foreach ($GroupMember in $listGroupMembers) {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Proprties mail  # use -Properties here to bring in other properties than default
    if ( $user.mail -like "*$searchstring*" ) { 
        $listOutput += $user 
        }
    }
$listOutput | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "c:\temp\evilcorpusers.csv" # put real file path here
```